# Sequelize - How to execute queries in sequence?

Tags: javascript, mysql, promise, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize 3.24.3 to connect to a MySQL database.

My requirement is to: execute query 1 and then execute query 2 after query 1 completes. Below is the code sample

```
Student.findOne({
    where:{
        userID:request.query.userID
    }
}).then(function(data){
    Papers.findAll({
            where:{
                userID:request.query.userID
            }
        }
    )
}).then(function (papers) {
    response.json({success: true,  paper: papers,});
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When the above runs: after findOne completes it calls the second "then" block and afterwards executes the findAll query. How can I prevent this and have it the queries executed sequentially?

Comment: simple ... `return Papers.findAll({` assuming `.findAll` returns a promise

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX ... I had to return both queries to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `Sequelize` you are also using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com).

You can use `.all` collection method, provided by the library. Read more about it [in the documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html).

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");

Promise.all([
    Student.findOne({ where : { userID: request.query.userID } }),
    Papers.findAll({ where : { userID: request.query.userID } })
]).spread( function( student, papers ) {
    response.json({success: true,  paper: papers });
}).catch( function( error ) { 
    console.log(err);
});
```

This will execute `Student.findOne` and `Papers.findAll` together and after they both return results it will call the `spread` method with the two results.